# How in streamlit get screen size?

Tags: python, streamlit

How to get page size in streamlit?
Can't find any documentation or examples

I tried like this:

```
from streamlit_js_eval import streamlit_js_eval

st.write(f"Screen width is {streamlit_js_eval(js_expressions='screen.width', key = 'SCR')}")
st.write(f"Screen height is {streamlit_js_eval(js_expressions='screen.height', key = 'SCR1')}")
```

but this one gives the size of the entire Screen and does not change when the page is changed

Comment: As shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_current_window.asp), maybe try `window.innerWidth` and `window.innnerHeight` instead of `screen.with` and `screen.height`. Haven't tested it, but would be the first thing I would try.